# Concatenting string what's the best way for doing that?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a query string that is formed in a std::string, the query has 4 points and each point has an x,y, each them of is of double datatype.

How would I concatenate the string to put the 4 points (8 variables) inside that query in c++

```
'MULTIPOINT(16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549)';
```

here is the form of the query:

```
string query = "SELECT * from areas WHERE st_contains(ST_ConvexHull(areas.GEOMETRY),st_mpointfromtext('MULTIPOINT(16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549)',4326));";




double x1 = 6.17951, x2 = 6.17951, x3 = 6.17951, x4 = 6.17951;
double y1 = 7.85549, y2 = 7.85549, y3 = 7.85549, y4 = 7.85549;

    /* std::string query = "SELECT * from areas WHERE st_contains(ST_ConvexHull(areas.GEOMETRY),st_mpointfromtext('MULTIPOINT(" 
                    + to_string(x1) + " " + to_string(y1) + ", " 
                    + to_string(x2) + " " + to_string(y2) + ", " 
                    + to_string(x3) + " " + to_string(y3) + ", " 
                    + to_string(x4) + " " + to_string(y4) + "',4326));";
 */

    string query = "SELECT * from areas WHERE st_contains(ST_ConvexHull(areas.GEOMETRY),st_mpointfromtext('MULTIPOINT(6.17951 7.85549, 6.17951 7.85549, 6.17951 7.85549, 6.17951 7.85549)',4326));";
```

Comment: sounds like you're looking for [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your input type there are a few options.

If you have a `std::string` then do like this:

```
std::string mp = "'MULTIPOINT(16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549)'";
std::string query = "SELECT * from areas WHERE st_contains(ST_ConvexHull(areas.GEOMETRY),st_mpointfromtext(" + mp + ",4326));";
```

If your input is `doubles`, and you use `C++11`, then you could do it like this:

```
std::string query = "SELECT * from areas WHERE st_contains(ST_ConvexHull(areas.GEOMETRY),st_mpointfromtext('MULTIPOINT(" 
                    + std::to_string(x1) + " " + std::to_string(y1) + ", " 
                    + std::to_string(x2) + " " + std::to_string(y2) + ", " 
                    + std::to_string(x3) + " " + std::to_string(y3) + ", " 
                    + std::to_string(x4) + " " + std::to_string(y4) + ")',4326));";
```

Comment: I have executed your query using to_string, but it does return the whole results of the query, however if I hardcode that points as shown in the edited post, it queries logically correct in terms of the output.

Comment: When something like this does not work, simply compare the two query strings. What is the difference?

Comment: There is no difference at all, that's weird.

Comment: The size of query one is larger than the size of query two by one byte.

Comment: ") this was missing